# Fadeing in and out multiple DIVs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

Could You be so kind and help with my jQuery problem? I'm run out of power thinking about it.

I have this kind of structure:

```
<div id="trigger-1">Trigger 1</div>
<div id="trigger-2">Trigger 2</div>
<div id="trigger-3">Trigger 3</div>
 ...
<div id="trigger-n">Trigger n</div>

<div id="content-1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content-2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content-3">Content 3</div>
 ...
<div id="content-n">Content n</div>
```

All objects are independent, I mean there is no relation parent -> child. What I want to get is fadeing in
DIV marked as a content after run a trigger with the same number in element ID. I know how to get it if I 
have for example 5 pairs of DIV, but I can't create script if I have unlimited pairs of divs.

Of course if content-1 DIV is visible, pressing trigger-2 triggers fadeOut for content-1 
and fadeIn for content-2.

Thank You for Your response.

Comment: I would really set classes for this, makes it a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('div[id^="trigger"]').click(
    function(){
        var num = this.id.match(/\d+/);
        $('div[id^="content-"]').fadeOut();
        $('#content-' + num).fadeIn();
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TNHHx/).

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it ;). You do mean #content in the second to last line, right?

Comment: +1 This is better than my solution although I think you mean content, not trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$('div[id^="trigger"]').click(function(){
   var id = this.id.slice(-1)
   $('div[id^="content"]').fadeOut();
   $('#content-'+id).fadeIn()
})
```

But it's better to use classes:

```
<div class='trigger' id="trigger-1">Trigger 1</div>
<div class='trigger' id="trigger-2">Trigger 2</div>
<div class='trigger' id="trigger-3">Trigger 3</div>
 ...
<div class='trigger' id="trigger-n">Trigger n</div>

<div class='content' id="content-1">Content 1</div>
<div class='content' id="content-2">Content 2</div>
<div class='content' id="content-3">Content 3</div>
 ...
<div class='content' id="content-n">Content n</div>
```

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
   var id = this.id.slice(-1)
   $('.content').fadeOut();
   $('#content-'+id).fadeIn()
})
```

Comment: This is a more simple approach, certainly, but it doesn't seem to account for any value of *`n`* beyond single-digits.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, you are correct, that's one of the downsides of using `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
    $('#trigger-'+i).click(function() {
        if($('#content-'+(i-1)).visible) $('#content-'+(i-1)).fadeOut();
        $('#content-'+i).fadeIn();
    });
}
```